# What biotechnology can be used to treat lazy eye, and possibly cure lazy eye?

Tags: biochemistry, neuroscience, molecular-genetics, neurophysiology, biotechnology

I tried very hard researching and finding the root cause of amblyopia. It is mainly because of imbalance in eye muscle. But, there are a lot more complicated causes of this disease. Thus, I need some help in finding a biotechnology for treating lazy eye.

Comment: I wish anyone could provide me a little clue.

Comment: Is it Graves disease cause by a thyroid problem ?

Comment: That's an extremely well documented subject on the net. there are even pages by doctors about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to treat amblyopia you first have to treat the initial problem with the eyes that caused it, which is a medical issue and probably not what you are asking anyway. However, as [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amblyopia) states, "after the underlying cause is fixed, vision is not restored right away, as the mechanism also involves the brain."

As a rule of thumb anything related to brain functions (in humans) is so complex that we don't really have the (bio)technology to just cure it. Sure, their are some advancements in a few areas, but especially if you want biotechnology to do this, you'll probably have to wait at least 10+ years for a medically save and readily usable method.